# How can I finally delete trackers that are pending for deletion?

Tags: tuleap

I have deleted several trackers. These trackers now appear in the "Trackers pending for Deletion". The list contains trackers that have been deleted months ago.

There is a "restore" button next to each tracker but no "delete" button.

How can I finally get rid of these deleted trackers? I have checked the Tuleap docs but did not find any information.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Tuleap team, this is not possible for now. They might add this option in some future version but no concrete timeline yet.